# unable to resolve, nslookup REFUSED with Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Does anyone have similar issues?
I've setup my domain on Google cloud,
same configuration as I've setup for another domain which works.
but recently, when I setup another domain, it failed.

I've used `dig` and `nslookup`, and it shows "REFUSED".
the headache part is, I've no where to go for support.

```
nslookup -debug wheelspine.com ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
Server:     ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
Address:    216.239.32.108#53

------------
QUESTIONS:
wheelspine.com, type = A, class = IN
ANSWERS:
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find wheelspine.com: REFUSED
Server:     ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
Address:    216.239.32.108#53

------------
QUESTIONS:
  wheelspine.com.lan, type = A, class = IN
ANSWERS:
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find wheelspine.com.lan: REFUSED
```

Comment: ive given up google cloud dns and switched back to my usual provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this problem with my domains too. After few hours I found out, that some of my domains are hosted on ns-cloud-dX.googledomains.com and some on ns-cloud-cX.googledomains.com. When you use incorrect address, dig shows refused.